# Matrix in caption breaking images alignment

Tags: graphics, matrices

I am trying to add some matrix show the convolution transformation over the same image, however one of the matrix is 5x5 and the others are 3x3. The problem is that I am not able to keep the images perfectly align.

**EDITED:**

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/random.eps}
    \caption[Network2]%
    {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&-4&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}    
    \label{fig:rand}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}  
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/sharpen.eps}
    \caption[]%
    {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1&0\\-1&5&-1\\0&-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}    
    \label{fig:sharpen}
\end{subfigure}
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}   
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_5.eps}
    \caption[]%
    {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}    
    \label{fig:edge_5}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}   
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_8.eps}
    \caption[]%
    {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&-1&-1\\-1&8&-1\\-1&-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}    
    \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[ Transformation of original image]
{\small Several convolution transformation of the original image. Each kernel gives a different configuration} 
\label{fig:edge_8}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

What should I do?

Regards!

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable document! Are your images have the same size? Try `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}` (observe `[t]` instead of `[b]`)

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I believe all the code can be compiled now, just to be sure, I am using PDFLatex to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Let mi convert my comment to an answer:

- the case when images have the same heights

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/random.eps}
        \caption[Network2]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&-4&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:rand}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/sharpen.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1&0\\-1&5&-1\\0&-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
        \label{fig:sharpen}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_5.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:edge_5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_8.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&-1&-1\\-1&8&-1\\-1&-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[ Transformation of original image]
    {Several convolution transformation of the original image. Each kernel gives a different configuration}
    \label{fig:edge_8}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- the case when images have different heights

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=43mm]{figs/random.eps}
        \caption[Network2]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&-4&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:rand}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=34mm]{figs/sharpen.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1&0\\-1&5&-1\\0&-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
        \label{fig:sharpen}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_5.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:edge_5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/edge_8.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&-1&-1\\-1&8&-1\\-1&-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[ Transformation of original image]
    {Several convolution transformation of the original image. Each kernel gives a different configuration}
    \label{fig:edge_8}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- if images have different heights, but you like to show with the same height, than define their height:

```
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=44mm]{figs/random.eps}
        \caption[Network2]%
        {$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&-4&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
        \label{fig:rand}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=44mm]{figs/sharpen.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1&0\\-1&5&-1\\0&-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
        \label{fig:sharpen}
    \end{subfigure}
```

Comment: I forgot to say, I changed the "b" by "t" but it still didn't work. Results look the same.

Comment: @Claudio, not with my MWE. You change something in my MWE or you haven't the same height of images. You not provide this information. From your comment follows, that it is not clear, what is your problem or what you like to  achieve. See edited answer.